# Python if elif in kickstart not handling variable

Tags: python, centos7

I know this must be something simple, but I'm too new to Python to see the problem.  I'm using Python in my CentOS7 kickstart %pre to configure a couple of include files for networking and partitioning on some KVM VMs.  Both the called functions work fine, if I leave out the if-elif-else block the installation completes as expected.

The way this is supposed to work is I pass three variables to the virt-install, like so:

```
virt-install <...> --extra-args "ks=cdrom:/ks-selector.cfg hostname IP Type"
```

The python script is called by the ks-selector and parses those last three arguments:

```
# Read in the command line and set up variables
with open('/proc/cmdline',  'r') as cmds:
  cmdVarsAll = cmds.readline()
cmds.close()
# Use split on ' ', drop the first value as it's the ks file
cmdVarsInstall = cmdVarsAll.split(' ')[1:]
hostName = cmdVarsInstall[0]
IP = cmdVarsInstall[1]
serverType = cmdVarsInstall[2]
```

Now, it handles setting the hostname and processes the IP as expected.  Where I get stuck is at the end, when it's time to pick the partition table function:

```
if serverType == "nginx100":
  n100Print()
elif serverType == "db100":
  db100Print()
else:
  notFound = open('/tmp/notFound',  'w')
  notFound.write(serverType)
```

I had entered 'db100' as the final argument, and indeed found it in my error file.  If I remove the if-then-else entirely and just call the db100Print() function, everything works as intended.  The installer version of Python is 2.7.

Any clues appreciated.

Comment: I didn't expect that to be a problem, the /proc/cmdline had no quotes and my error file showed just the variable, but adding the space at the end of the arguments works!

Comment: There was an earlier comment (that appears to have been deleted) that gave me the clue to try a space after the last variable.  Although that works I'd be interested to hear any comments that might clarify why.